# Sitecore powershell get-user command

Tags: powershell, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8

We have over 200k users in our sitecore system.  I need to export a list of users who meet a certain criteria.  I am using a powershell script for this and I am using the get-user command to retrieve the users.  I am then looping through the list of users and picking those that meet my criteria; in my case those users who are older than 18.  I am then writing the result out to a csv file using export-csv.  I find that this is taking over 1.5 hours to complete.

My question is, is there a way I can do a get-user and specify my criteria of age older than 18?  The field age is stored in a custom property.  Also, any other efficient ways (other than powershell) of accomplishing what I am trying to do here?

Here is the original code:

```
function export($user)
{
    $age = $user.profile.GetCustomProperty("age")

    if{$age -gt 18)
    {
        $id = $user.profile.GetCustomProperty("id")
        $firstname = $user.profile.GetCustomProperty("first name")

        $user | select-object -property @{Name="First Name";Expression={$firstname}}, 
            @{Name="Age";Expression={$age}}, 
            @{Name="ID";Expression={$id}} |
        Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\out.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

$users = get-user -Filter * 

if($users -ne $null)
{
    $users | foreach {export($_)}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example script showing what you doing now to query the users and filter?

Comment: Thanks for the code. I updated my response with an example that should work for you. The keys are case sensitive for the custom properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Based on your example I can see why it takes so long. You are exporting to CSV for every iteration.

Try this:

```
$users = Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.Profile.GetCustomProperty("age") -gt 18 } 

$property = @(
    "Name",
    @{Name="First Name";Expression={$PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty("first name")}}, 
    @{Name="Age";Expression={$PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty("age")}}, 
    @{Name="ID";Expression={$PSItem.Profile.GetCustomProperty("id")}}
)
$users | Select-Object -Property $property | Export-CSV -Path c:\temp\out.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

**Old comments:**

The more I look at it I'm doubting that this can be done. The age property should be serialized and stored on the profile. Unless there is a faster way to extract the profile date, I'm not sure of what else can be done to speed things up.

I suspect you are doing something like this:

```
Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object { $_.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Age") -gt 18 }
```

I don't know a faster way than this.

Comment: I have added my original code to the question.  I modified my code as you suggested and it definitely runs faster.  It's now taking close to 30 minutes vs. over 1.5 hours with the original code.  Can I have the Get-User command return only the fields that I am interested in?  That ought to improve the performance even more no?

Comment: Thanks for accepting. How long does it take to run now?

Comment: it's now taking 20 - 25 minutes to run; a significant improvement.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for sharing. I've also added your sample to the book here: https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/users-and-roles.html . You should also remove -Append from my sample since it will keep adding to the existing file.

Answer (score 2):

> I am then looping through the list of users and picking those that
>   meet my criteria

You should not be doing this. Instead filter the users directly with Get-User

```
Get-User -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.age -ge 18}
```

As another example, I'll filter users who are over 18 and whose first name begins with "Ste".

```
Get-User -Filter * -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object {$_.age -ge 18 -and $_.FirstName -like "Ste*"}
```

Comment: I see a few issues with your examples. 1) ResultSize is not a property available on the command. 2) Age is a custom property and should be accessed from the profile.

Comment: Are you sure? Check out Example 1 -- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996896(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: @sqone2 That's not the `Get-User` cmdlet in question - [*this is*](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Get-User.html)